# How to do directional finding with Bluetooth and UWB

Tags: bluetooth, direction-finding, uwb, positioning

Just jumped into the ocean of IoT and found myself drowning....

I am trying to make my small toy car(with remote) being able to follow me.

Have discussed with my hardware friend and was told to get

1. [UWB](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005002284315770.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.26fc3c00YJXtrI&mp=1) to detecting the distance
2. [Bluetooth 5.1](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003035990314.html?spm=a2g0o.cart.0.0.26fc3c00YJXtrI&mp=1) for directional positioning

However when I searched online, I found so many variations for the Bluetooth 5.1. (It has to be at least BLE 5.1 to be able to do the directional positioning)

The one BLE I provided link here with title BLE 5.1, but then also having picture saying it supports Bluetooth 5.0 which makes me confuse about which exactly version it supports.
Talked to the store staff, no responses.....

Can someone suggest a few products for the Bluetooth?

Also , could someone share some code for how to use them in Python or MicroPython, if no code available in Python, C++ is okay...

---

**Update 1**

Hi guys,

An interesting found, a few days ago, I was trying to pointing my 5G router to the direction of 5G signal tower. After made a call to my mobile phone service provider, I installed an My Account app.

By using this app, I am able to find the correct direction for my 5G router to point to. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

As you can see that the pointer in the middle of the screen rotates when I rotate my mobile phone.

Isn't this the exactly functionality I am looking for?

Does anyone know how it is achieved?
Could this be the gyro sensor???

I can't figure out why I had been ignoring gyro sensor the whole time, but it looks like the device I'm looking for, right?

Comment: I don’t think you would need both, as far as I know UWB can do direction finding as well as long as you have the appropriate hardware (iPhones can show the direction to an AirTag nearby for instance). Just need to find the right hardware…

Comment: hi @jcaron after reading at least 5 articles each for UWB and BLE 5.1, I found that yes UWB will be capable of doing directional finding, BUT we need at least 3 or 4 UWB used as anchors and 1 UWB used as tag to do so. As to BLE, it only became capable of doing directional finding after version 5.1.

Comment: https://graz.pure.elsevier.com/en/publications/direction-finding-with-uwb-and-ble-a-comparative-study

Comment: @Franva Just to be clear: "`As to BLE, it only became capable of doing directional finding after version 5.1`". That is true, but, as I learned the hard way, it does not mean that BLE 5.1+ deceives support it. I have had no luck finding a decent dev board :-(

Comment: thanks @jcaron for sharing the publications. I never looked into a publication, will spend time to figure it out.

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica How about this one? (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/CDSENET-2-4GHz-E104-BT5011A-TB-Bluetooth-to-Serial-Port-Transparent-Transmission-Module-BLE5-1-Module/1005003035990314.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.2ead4c4dbrStMu) I have ordered 2 today. We can even pair up to try to learn how to use it.

Comment: Hmmm, the title says BLE 5.1, but the rest of the page says 5.0. In any case, not all 5.1 has AoA & AoD, which you need for location. Your referenced AliExpress item uses the nRF52811, but it's [web page](https://www.nordicsemi.com/products/nrf52811) does not mention location or AoA / AoD, ***BUT***, the [linked specification](https://www.nordicsemi.com/-/media/Software-and-other-downloads/Product-Briefs/nRF52811-product-brief.pdf) does, so, yes, it looks great. Let's hope that it has some sample code ;-)

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica the chip is capable of performing direction finding, but you need a switched antenna array to go with it, which I doubt the module has. Also this specific module seems to be designed solely to act as a serial/BLE bridge, though you may be able to reprogram the 52811 with other firmware.

Comment: IC, IC. Thanks (+1). I currently have 2 questions open on h/w recommendations asking for a 5.1 dev board with AoA & AoD. Maybe you can answer? Maybe you can reword & tell me what extra kit I need? I would be extremely grateful. They are [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13654/ble-5-1-wearable-dev-board-with-aoa-and-aod) and [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/12435/ble5-1-with-on-board-or-snap-on-display-with-aoa-and-aod). I just want to get on with developing an app, but am not sure what h/w I need. Sample code would be great too :-)

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica yep, I am confused too. The title says one thing, the content says other thing~! I will have to wait to my parcel and hopefully it works. Meanwhile, I will try to find some example codes.

Comment: @jcaron yes, I did see that some articles mentioned about the Antenna Array(AA). However I could not find where I can buy it at all..... so disappointed. Could you please share its link? Appreciated~!

Comment: Or, even better, an answer ;-)

Comment: Regarding the update, yes, most phones contain a compass (magnetometer) which they can use to know which way is (magnetic) north compared to the phone and thus the heading of the phone. Google maps has been using that for ages. But how is that related to direction finding or your goal of tracking a device (or having a device track you)?

Comment: @jcaron probably not. My phone does not have UWB, in my update 1 I saw it's able to find direction pointing to the 5G signal station. Just wondering how it does that??

Comment: It's not pointing to the 5G signal station, just pointing in the same direction as your phone I believe, like Google Maps for instance. It uses a magnetometer (compass) which tells it where North is compared to your phone, so it knows where the phone is pointing compared to your phone (known as heading). All iPhones and most Android phones have one.

Comment: @jcaron I think I got your point. It works for locating a 5G signal station as the 5G station is a few hundreds of meters away from me, so the accuracy of GPS + compass would be enough. But it won't be enough for a following bot as the bot will be less 1 meter away from me. So I guess I won't be able to use its(5G station finder) method in my application.

Answer (score 1):

With direction-finding, you usually need a bunch of coordinating devices working together to estimate direction. Look at Silabs [white paper for Bluetooth 5.1 AoA and AoD](https://www.silabs.com/wireless/bluetooth/bluetooth-5-1). I don't think this tech is ready for a hobbyist just yet. But, if you've got experience with development kits, then go for it. Silabs has a [BG22 module](https://www.silabs.com/wireless/gecko-series-2/efr32bg22) that you could look at.

Comment: Hi Matthew, yes I saw that as well. Could you please have a look my update 1?

Comment: Hey Franva. Yeah gyros are cool and can work but you’ll have to calibrate them every now and then. Gyros suffer from drift like all dead-wreckoning systems. After some time, the direction estimate will get worse and worse. You’ll have to have another system to periodically realign the direction correctly.

Comment: Hi @Matthew, I am thinking may I make it unnecessary complicated? If you read my Update 1, you would see that my phone Oppo Find X2 Pro, does not have UWB, yet it is still able to find the direction pointing to the 5G signal station. How does it do it???

Comment: thanks @matthew, then I guess I can conclude that for now, technically it is possible, but practically it's not that easy.